# ReactJS change props inside of a custom component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im new at React and Im currently having problems accessing the props inside a custom component.

So I have a custom Component `CustomDatePicker` (which I can edit), that uses another custom component `Date` (which I cannot edit). Inside the `Date` component there is a `react-datepicker` which I would like to extend.

**CustomDatePicker**

```
export class CustomDatePicker extends Model.FormComponent {
  render() {
    const Date = this.props.Components.date;
    const datepickerProps = {datepickerProps: {showYearDropdown: false}};

    return <Date {...this.props} {...datepickerProps}/>;
  }
};
```

**DateComponent**

```
export default class DateComponent extends StatefulFormComponent {
       render() {
                const datepickerProps = Object.assign(
                {
                       placeholderText: this.getFromConfig("placeholder")
                }
                return (
                       <DatePicker
                       {...datepickerProps}
                        />
               )
        }
}
```

Is there anway to access the datepickerProps and add a new value like `showYearDropdown: false`?

Comment: Really depends on how `Date` is implemented.

Comment: You have the code for `DateComponent`. Why not copy it into a new component that you can edit and use that?

Comment: As I understand you just want to implement this to hide year dropdown. Can not you use just css display: none to do that?